# Se puede encriptar el path route de angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Por ejemplo si tengo algo asi en router module:

{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}

puedo encriptar 'home' y se muestre algo asi como localhost/dhfjcbjkyf43rf

Ya encripto el path pero al momento que lo asigno al routerLink me manda al inicio ya que dhfjcbjkyf no existe en los routes, no se como pueda encriptar y la url traiga esa encriptacion y desencriptar cuando ya entre al router module y m elleve al home sin ningun problema

Comment: Si, es posible, pero dependiendo de la complejidad de tu aplicacion se puede convertir en un dolor de cabeza (de la manera que se me ocurre). Seria utilizando una ruta que acepte todo, y dentro de esa ruta redirijes a un componente que coincida. Pero, es necesario encriptar tu url?

Comment: y cual seria el objetivo de encriptar la ruta?

Comment: Encriptar la ruta solo te dara dolor de cabeza, entiendo que puede ser para proteger el nombre real de las rutas y otros propositos, pero esa ruta definitivamente te daria diferentes tipos de problemas con angular, si fuese una pagina web que no usase angular seria distinto... pero al usar angular hay que tener mas cuidado con las rutas.

Comment: @MiguelZarate, Angel por seguridad solamente, pero todos me comentan lo mismo, que sera un dolor de cabeza. gracias por sus respuestas